# How to install «Hip Hop» on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, music, tar, music-player

I would like to try [Hip Hop](http://gethiphop.net/) on Ubuntu 14.04, but on the website, there is only a `.tgz` file, and I have no idea how to install it. There is no `.deb` in the compressed file.

Does anyone have an idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. This works :

```
tar xvzf HipHop-0.4.6.tgz
cd HipHop/
chmod +x HipHop
sudo apt-get install libudev1:i386
sudo ln -sf /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.0
```

To run, type

```
./HipHop
```

Comment: How to run the application?

Comment: After you used chmod +x HipHop, you can just double click on "HipHop" on the folder, or use ./HipHop